# IndexController: loadLayout() not working inside postAction() (Helper_Data not found)

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, post-data

I always get following error when calling *$this->loadLayout()* inside *postAction()* of my IndexController:

*Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Package_MyModule_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\Mage.php on line 547*

*$this->renderLayout()* doesn't give me an error.

**IndexController:**

```
class Package_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function testAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


    public function postAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        //Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::loadLayout();
    }
}
```

I also tried to call the method directly out of the class *Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action* but it still gives me the same error. *indexAction()* and *testAction()* do work as expected.

**config.xml:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_MyModule>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </Package_MyModule>
    </modules>


    <frontend>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <package_mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </package_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>

        <routers>
             <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                  <args>
                     <module>Package_MyModule</module>
                     <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                  </args>
             </mymodule>
        </routers>

    </frontend>


    <global>

        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Package_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
        </models>

        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Package_MyModule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>

    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Package/MyModule/Helper/**Data.php:**

```
class Package_MyModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

/layout/**mymodule.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <mymodule_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="default_mymodule_view" template="mymodule/view.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_index_index>

</layout>
```

I think I got everything necessary at the right place. I have no idea why it isn't working inside postAction().

Comment: Why there is `Mage` in `Mage_Package_MyModule_Helper_Data` line? Could you add your full config.xml?

Comment: can you show your layout.xml file?

Comment: I added full config.xml and my layout.xml in the main post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite sure you are using `$this->__()` inside of `mymodule/view.phtml`. Therefore you need a `Helper_Data` in your module.

In the config you have node `global/helpers/mymodule`, this node has to contain the Prefix of your helper, in this case `MP_Berater_Helper` (the same for the models.

And the name of the class has to be the same as the path, so either you rename your class to `Package_MyModule_Helper_Data` or you change the path to `MP/Berater/Helper/Data.php`

Comment: Was a mistake of mine, I changed the actuall Package and Module name (in the question) to "Package" and "MyModule" to keep things clear. I fixed it in the main post.

Comment: Did you clear your cache since updateing your config?

Comment: It's disabled in my testing enviroment.

Comment: then you should check where your helper is called from (stacktrace) and why it doesn't work. I think we can't help here.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your **config.xml** with the following:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <package_mymodule>
            <class>Package_MyModule_Model</class>
        </package_mymodule>
    </models>

    <helpers>
        <package_mymodule>
            <class>Package_MyModule_Helper</class>
        </package_mymodule>
    </helpers>

</global>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it though I dont know how. I had to reinstall magento. My installation must have been corrupted although it was pretty new. Same code is working on freshly installed magento.